# Navigation block title no longer defaulting to user name in d7

Tags: 7, navigation

The default behavior for the Navigation block in d6 was to replace the word Navigation with the user name.  It appears that this logic was removed from the core user module in d7.  My client stills wants the user name to display.  Is there a way to duplicate this same behavior in d7 ??

What complicates things a bit is that we are using a mini panel that includes that block but I haven't figured out a way to override the title with the user name.  I've tried using the user:name token as the Navigation block title and then overriding the title with %title but it displays the literal value 'user:name' instead of the actual user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set "user" in the contexts? It sounds like you do not have access to the %user:name token, and that's why it sets the actual text instead of the username.

Answer (score 1):

This is the covered by the use case of the [Block Title Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_titlelink) module. It allows you to replace any block title with your arbitrary title/link with token support (e.g. `[current-user:name]`). If you're just looking to rename the block title (without a link), you can leave the link field empty and just rewrite the title display.